# How to get the ceiling function and floor function value of $\frac{2+4\sqrt{3}}{5}$?

Tags: number-theory

I want to the know the solution procedure of the following so that in future I can use it.

Its very simple related to floor and ceiling function for any real number $x$.

Suppose that $x=\frac{2+4\sqrt{3}}{5}$. If we use any scientific calculator to convert it in to floating number it will be done easily. And then getting the values of ceiling function and floor function of $x$ are easy jobs.

But manually how to get the values is my question.

Please help me the steps by which we can get the ceiling value and floor values of the real numbers in this form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can estimate the interval on which a square root falls, since

$$4\sqrt 3 = \sqrt{3\cdot 16} = \sqrt{48}.$$

you know that $6=\sqrt{36} < 4\sqrt{3}<\sqrt{49} = 7$. So, since $4\sqrt{3}$ is between $6$ and $7$, you know that $2+4\sqrt{3}$ is between $8$ and $9$, making the fraction somewhere between $\frac85$ and $\frac95$, or in other words,

$$\frac85< \frac{2+4\sqrt3}{5}<\frac95.$$

This estimate is good enough to calculate the value of the floor and ceiling functions.

Comment: Superb and innovative answer. Thank you so much

Comment: @AnjanDebnath I don't know about the innovative part, but thank you:)

Comment: Ok fine. Impressive !! Now how about that ? :-D